# Beats Audio not working

Tags: windows-8

My laptop(Dv6 6121 Tx) supports beats audio.However after upgrading to windows 8 I am finding a decrease in the quality of sound which I was getting before.The possible reasons could be that my front speakers are not supported by drivers properly.

I have tried upgrading my drivers but I find no change in the quality.Some time some weird noise also comes from speakers.Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[Ask Beats](http://www.beatsbydre.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-beats-Site/default/CustomerService-ContactUs) about Windows 8 support. If they help you resolve the issue, please edit with the details.